# не работает роутинг после деплоя на gh pages react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, router

Не могу понять почему не работает роутинг на деплое

```
 App.tsx
<div className="app">
        <div>asd</div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/rooms/:id" component={RoomPage} />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={HomePage} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
index.tsx 
 const app = (
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: А сервер на чем?

Comment: попробуйте использовать HashRouter, результат будет тот же?